# DotNetZip library on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have been trying to add dotnetzip to my windows phone 8 project without luck. I tried adding it via nuget but it fails to add with the message "not compatible with any projects in the solution". The package targets NetFramwork Version=v2.0".I also downloaded its binary from codeplex but still they don't get added. How do i add it to the project. Where can i find DotNetZip library for windows phone. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the **DotNetZip** library to be used in a Windows Phone app, it must itself be a portable class library that targets the Windows Phone 8.1 platform. You could download the source from its CodePlex page and see if it can be compiled within a portable class library that targets the Windows Phone 8.1 platform.

However... check out the `System.IO.Compression` namespace which contains the `ZipArchive` type. This type allows you to read existing archives and perform updates on them too. From looking at the [System.IO.Compression MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Compression(v=vs.110).aspx), there is also a **ZipFile** type which allows creating new archives, but its not available in the Windows Phone 8.1 API unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using SharpZipLib now. Somewhere i had read that DotNetZip is faster than SharpZipLib, so wanted to try that. Will try making it portable.